# Metrics for Change Size when using diff tools

Tags: diff, metrics

Does anybody know any diff tool which counts some metrics for "Change Size". I'm searching for a diff tool that uses the diff output and reports something like:

1. The number of changed/added/removed attributes;
2. The number of changed/added/removed operations;
3. The nunmber of changed class' "extends/implements";
4. The nunmber of changed class' name/package

   ...

It should be, of course, an AST diff tool. A simple text-based diff tool won't be able to do that.

This report would be interesting to give the designer the dimension of a change between two versions of the code.

Answer (score 0):

See our [SD Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer), which computes an AST-based (tree) difference and reports the changes made in terms of grammar tokens (terminals and nonterminals) and the actions applied to them (insert, delete, move, copy, rename-identifier-within).

It doesn't provide the statistics you want directly, but you could use the identified grammar tokens to classify the changes according to your categories above (you'd need the grammar to do that; use the one in the Java reference manual).

Comment: Hi, prof. Ira. Recently I've tried the SD Smart Differencer tool. It's nice and certainly it can be a good idea to use the Smart Differencer output to count the statistics that I need.                                                                Another alternative is to extend the Eclipse Compare Feature. I guess it's possible too.                                                                 But I posted here because I was thinking that there might be a tool which already do that.